# Force regression to first data point ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a problem with forcing a polynomial regression to start at the first observation on the x axis. It needs to be dynamic because I am making faceted plots.

A reproducible example: I want the line to start on the blue marked dots in the plot created by this snippet:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am) %>% 
  mutate(first_point = if_else(hp == min(hp), 1, 0))

ggplot(df, aes(hp, qsec, 
               color = as.factor(first_point),
               size = as.factor(first_point))) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm", 
               se = F,
               formula = y ~ poly(x, 3)) +
   facet_wrap(~ am)
```

Basically what i want (which does not work) is this formula in geom_smooth:

```
formula = qsec ~ min(hp) + poly(hp, 3)
```

Hope anyone knows a trick :)

Comment: You should first develop a solution outside ggplot2. Then you can work on passing that to ggplot2. Basically, you want a regression model without intercept but with an offset. This comment makes no judgment regarding the suitability of such a model.

Comment: @Roland Thanks Roland for answer. The fix is for pedagogic reason rather than econometric :) Would you know a good start to fix it outside ggplot?